# Add jars to Docker image from Plugin Directory

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, jar, dockerfile

I have a spring boot application which contains a Main Class. I have Docker File as below:

```
FROM docker.io/openjdk:11-jre-slim
EXPOSE 8082
EXPOSE 8443
ADD target/base-application.jar app.jar
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -jar /app.jar
```

I am creating a Docker image by using this Docker file. Let's consider that this docker file is `Docker1`.

I have another Spring Boot application (which doesn't have a Main class) with Docker file as below:

```
FROM Docker1:0.0.1
EXPOSE 8443
ADD target/child-application.jar child-application.jar
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -jar /app.jar
```

I am using `Docker1` as a base image for the docker image of 2nd application. I am running the Main class of `Docker1` by running 2nd Docker image. Now there are 2 jar files of another spring boot projects(`messagepack1.jar` &  `messagepack2.jar`). I want to load these jars in the 2nd docker image. I am trying something like this:

```
FROM Docker1:0.0.1
EXPOSE 8443
COPY src/main/resources/message-packs/messagepack1.jar m1.jar
COPY src/main/resources/message-packs/messagepack2.jar m2.jar
ADD target/child-application.jar child-application.jar
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -jar /app.jar
```

But it is not loading the jars when I am running the 2nd Docker image. Can you please help me out?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not loading the jars"? In what way do you want to load them? I suspect that you wanted to use them in classpath, or?

Comment: Yes @SashaShpota, I want to use them in classpath, just like Maven dependency. But we don't want to use Maven Dependency approach. This is the prerequisite.

Comment: I am pretty sure you don't need to solve this on Docker level. Spring Boot is a fat jar, just like any other dependencies, you can pack your two jars into the app jar.

Comment: Do you mean to say that I should use Maven dependency to pack the external jars into app.jar?

Comment: I mean that you need to include the dependencies to classpath (doesn't matter what tool you use for it). Using Docker images for this feels weird. But you have not provided sufficient information to understand what you want so we can only guess.

Comment: In future, we can have multiple external jar files. If we add these as a dependency, every time we need to update our pom.xml file and we will also have to build our application. But if we can load these jars using Dockerfile, we can skip the build process.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I could find the solution to this problem:

```
ADD /src/main/resources/message-packs /external-jars

ENTRYPOINT exec java -cp app.jar -Dloader.path=external-jars/ -Dloader.main=com.example.MainClass org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

Here, I am adding the External Jars from src/main/resources/message-packs directory to the "external-jars" folder of the Docker Image. Then I am loading these jars to the Classpath of my application by using "java -cp" command.